# objects as keys in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use an object as a key in a python dictionary, but it's behaving in a way that I can't quite understand.

First I create a dictionary with my object as the key:

```
package_disseminators = {
  ContentType("application", "zip", "http://other/property") : "one",
  ContentType("application", "zip") : "two"
}
```

Now create another object that is "the same" as one which is a key.

```
content_type = ContentType("application", "zip", "http://other/property")
```

I have given the ContentType object custom `__eq__` and custom `__str__` methods, such that the `__eq__` method compares the `__str__` values.

Now, some interactive python:

```
>>> for key in package_disseminators:
...     if key == content_type:
...             print "match"
...     else:
...             print "no match"
... 
no match
match

>>> content_type in package_disseminators.keys()
True
```

Ok, so it looks like my object is definitely being identified properly as a key, so:

```
>>> package_disseminators[content_type]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: (& (type="application/zip") (packaging="http://other/property") )
```

Er ... ok?  So content_type is in the package_disseminators.keys() list, but isn't a key?

```
>>> package_disseminators.has_key(content_type)
False
```

Apparently not.

I presume that the comparison process that Python uses to determin equality differs between a straight "in" statement on a list and actually looking up a key in a dict, but I don't know how.  Any tips or insights?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the python documentation:

> A dictionary’s keys are almost
>   arbitrary values. Values that are not
>   hashable, that is, values containing
>   lists, dictionaries or other mutable
>   types (that are compared by value
>   rather than by object identity) may
>   not be used as keys.

[Hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable) is defined as follows

> An object is hashable if it has a hash
>   value which never changes during its
>   lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()`
>   method), and can be compared to other
>   objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or
>   `__cmp__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same
>   hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as
>   a dictionary key and a set member,
>   because these data structures use the
>   hash value internally.

So if you want to do this, you need to override the default `__hash__()` method on your object (see the comment from Steven Rumbalski below for further explanation).

---

```
>>> content_type in package_disseminators.keys()
True
```

I suppose this works because `dict.keys()` returns a list, and `__contains__` probably checks for equality, but not for the same hashes.

Comment: Some further clarification:  Your object already has a `__hash__` method inherited from `object`.  But the default implementation returns a unique value for each instance, so two equal instances will have different hashes unless you provide a better implementation.  `has_key` compares hash values, `in` checks for equality, that's why `has_key` fails while `in` succeeds in your examples.

Answer (score 36):

Since dicts are hash tables under the hood, you need to define both `__eq__` and `__hash__` for that to work.

The basic rule of thumb is:

- For objects that `__eq__` compares equal, `__hash__` must return the same hash.

From your description, something like

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(str(self))
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation of `__hash__`!  Unfortunately I can't allocate two right answers to a question, although the combination of yours and the other are everything that I need.  Cheers, R.