# Custom object does not properly work as dictionary key even after overwriting __hash__() and __eq__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

**NOTE**: I am aware of this exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994229/how-to-make-an-object-properly-hashable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950155/objects-as-keys-in-python-dictionaries?rq=1). However, I have tried the solutions proposed by the answers there and they do not work for me (see sample code below).

---

A `B` object has a list of `A`. `A` is composed by a tuple of only two integers and an integer.

I am trying to use `B` objects as keys in a dictionary. However, even after implementing my own `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods, the length of my dictionary increases even after adding the same object to it.

See code below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_tuple, my_integer):
        self.my_tuple = my_tuple
        self.my_integer = my_integer
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.my_tuple == other.my_tuple and self.my_integer == other.my_integer

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_A = []
    def add(self, my_tuple, my_integer):
        new_A = A(my_tuple, my_integer)
        self.list_of_A.append(new_A)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(repr(self))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        for i in range(len(self.list_of_A)):
            if self.list_of_A[i] != other.list_of_A[i]:
                return False
        return True

b_1 = B()
b_1.add((1,2), 3)

b_2 = B()
b_2.add((1,2), 3)

my_dict = {}

my_dict[b_1] = 'value'
print(len(my_dict))

my_dict[b_2] = 'value_2'
print(len(my_dict))
```

The output I am getting is

> 1
> 2

And the expected output is

> 1
> 1

Because I am adding the same object (i.e.:same properties values).

Comment: `hash(repr(self))` is not an appropriate hash in this case. Two equal objects will not have the same hash with this implementation. You need a hash that's consistent based on the values you consider for equality.

Comment: `b_1` and `b_2` are considered different key since their hash values will differ. Usually the default repr of an object contains its memory address and that is different for both objects, and the hash of them as well.

Comment: you implemented `hash`, but that uses `repr` which you didn't implement... So that will return a default `<__main__.B object at 0x03755090>` where the last number is the address in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashes aren't equal because the `repr()`s aren't equal. Consider the following example I just did on my python console using your code:

```
>>> x = B()
>>> y = B()
>>> repr(x)
'<__main__.B object at 0x7f7b3a20c358>'
>>> repr(y)
'<__main__.B object at 0x7f7b3aa197b8>'
```

Obviously, `x` and `y` will have different hashes.

All you need to do, then, is overwrite `__repr__()` so that it outputs a deterministic value based on the contents of the object, rather than its memory address, and you should be good to go. In your case, that may look something like this:

```
class A:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A(my_tuple:{self.my_tuple}, my_integer:{self.my_integer})"

class B:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"B(list_of_a:{self.list_of_a})"
```